# get latest added term from taxonomy and insert into php variable

Tags: wp-query

I have a taxonomy called `mailers`

And I am adding new terms to this taxonomy on a monthly basis.

For example these are my 4 recent terms (slugs) I have added...

```
'august-2012-newsletter'
'july-2012-newsletter'
'june-2012-newsletter'
'may-2012-newsletter'
```

Is there anyway way to get the latest added term and added it to my `$mailer` variable?

Instead of having manually type the latest term in every month?

```
$mailer = 'august-2012-newsletter';

$articles = new WP_Query(array(

    'mailers'       => $mailer, 
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'orderby'       => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key'      => 'mailer_order',
    'post_type'     => 'post'

));
```

Thank you so much for any ideas :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest term means it'll have the highest term_ID right, So we're sorting terms in `DESC` order and getting first array element of the result in `$latest_mailer` variable.

Here's code to do that, not tested but if didn't worked - you can modify [`get_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) function to return term with higest `id`.

```
$mailer = get_terms('mailers','orderby=id&order=DESC&number=1');
$latest_mailer = $mailer[0]->slug;
```